# Can ANTLR's Visitor system automatically visit a rule context when a file is parsed?

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I been using ANTLR for a month now and I'm still no expert. I wanted to know if ANTLR's `BaseVisitor` class that is generated, automatically visits a specific rule context once the `visitRuleContext()` is implemented and the file to be parsed is done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you look into the generated visitor class, you'll see that all methods return `visitChildren(ctx)`. So when you only override one `visit...(...)` method in your own visitor, your single method would be called.

A quick test shows this:

```
grammar T;

parse
 : something+ EOF
 ;

something
 : ANY+
 | number
 ;

number
 : DIGITS
 ;

DIGITS
 : [0-9]+
 ;

ANY
 : .
 ;
```

And a test class:

```java
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(CharStreams.fromString("mu 123"));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    ParseTree root = parser.parse();
    new TestVisitor().visit(root);
  }
}

class TestVisitor extends TBaseVisitor<Object> {
  @Override
  public Object visitSomething(TParser.SomethingContext ctx) {
    System.out.println("visitSomething: " + ctx.getText());
    return super.visitChildren(ctx);
  }
}
```

will print:

```
visitSomething: mu 
visitSomething: 123
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wanted to be absolutely before I incorporated this concept in my compiler.